# Vagrant: download boxes from S3 (with MFA)

Tags: amazon-s3, vagrant, multi-factor-authentication

All our vagrant boxes are stored on a private AWS s3, we used a plugin called vagrant-s3auth to download them. A week ago a policy update forced us to use MFA for authentication. I spent days finding a new plugin but no success. Most of the users aren't that tech-savy so a workaround is really my last option. I have basic ruby skills so I'm able to do some modifications to the plugin.

Many thanks,
Sammy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why -1? Solved the problem. Fairly new plugin called "vagrant-s3auth-mfa". Tried it before and didn't work, seems to be updated.
https://github.com/vrtdev/vagrant-s3auth